# Are there any problems which are known to be both NP-complete and EXPTIME-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Are there any problems which are known to be both NP-complete and EXPTIME-compelte?  My guess is no, because we know that $P$ is not equal to $EXPTIME$ and EXPTIME-complete problems are not in $P$, and hence a problem that was both NP-complete and EXPTIME-complete would imply $P \not= NP$.  Is my thinking correct?

Note that in a difference in notation, here $EXPTIME=EXP$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not currently known. If such a problem were known, it would prove that:

$$NP=EXPTIME$$

Incidentally, it would also prove that $NP=PSPACE$, because it is known that:

$$P \subseteq NP \subseteq PSPACE \subseteq EXPTIME$$

We don't know which of these subset relations are strict subset relations, but at least one of them must be, because by the time hierarchy theorem:

$$P \subset EXPTIME$$

Comment: So just to verify, from what you stated this would imply $P \not= NP$ since we need a strict subset, and since NP and PSPACE and EXPTIME would all be equal, this would mean that the only possible strict subset is P is a strict subset of NP?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I suppose that's true, yes.